# Why does this write outfile not work on different SPSS versions?

Tags: spss

I have a data set consisting of variables `id, condition, response`. I have the following syntax to generate an Excel file, say, for data cleaning:

```
compute tab=9.
formats tab (pib).
write outfile='Directory\outfile.xls' / " if id = " tab id tab " and condition = " tab condition tab " response = ". 
execute.
```

The variable `tab` is created to separate the outputs (text, variables) in the `write outfile` command into different cells in Excel file.
I run the syntax on one computer (SPSS 23, 64-bit) and it works as expected, like this:

```
|if id = | 1 | and condition = | 2 |response =|
```

Each `|` represent a cell.

However, I run on another computer (SPSS 23, 32-bit) and it doesn't work. It particular, it dumps all fields from the `write outfile` into one single cell. It looks like this

```
|if id = 1 and condition = 2 response =|
```

Can you tell what may go wrong? I suspect it has something to do with variable `tab`. And what does `pib` format mean?

UPDATE: I try to write outfile in text format and the tab works OK.

```
write outfile='Directory\outfile.txt' / " if id = " tab id tab " and condition = " tab condition tab " response = ".
```

Answer (score 1):

The WRITE command is always creating a text file regardless of the file extension. (SAVE TRANSLATE could create Excel files directly.). So the difference may be on the Excel side.  Looking at the WRITE output as a hex dump would show for sure what is being written.

PIB format stands for Positive Integer Binary.  It is used here to say to treat 9 as a character code rather than the numeric value 9.  9 is the character code for a tab.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I try several times and it's the same: Syntax works on one computer but not on the other. While I will figure out what goes wrong, the .txt output format is the temporary solution. Can you tell where I can read more about the PIB format and the like? I do some search but see nothing specific to SPSS.

Comment: But compare the text files generated on the two systems.  They should be identical.  As for PIB, you can read about PIB and the related IB and PIBHEX formats in the Command Syntax Reference accessible from the Help menu.  If you want to send me the two files, I can inspect them in a hex dump (jkpeck@gmail.com)

Comment: Thank you for the reference hint, and yes these files look the same, apparently except for the format. As for sending the files, I appreciate that very much but I'm not sure if I can due to data confidentiality. I'll see if I can create hypothetical data sets with the same problems.